# Одновременная работа с MySQL и MS SQL на C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

Работаю на C#: `System.Data.SqlClient` и `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`. Есть две базы: локальная на MS SQL и удаленная на MySQL. С локальной я получаю данные (в `[System.Data.]DataSet`, в моем случае). В ответе одно поле содержит ID'ы, записи с какими мне необходимо выбрать из удаленной базы на MySQL.

Можно, конечно, просто перебрать все записи и по каждому ID'у делать выборку из удаленной базы. Но, в таком случае запросов будет слишком много и время выполнения будет не очень приятным.

Можно ли как-то сделать это проще, разумнее?

**Проще говоря**:
Получаем данные из локальной MS SQL с полем ID => Выбираем все записи из удаленной MySQL, в которых поле ID2 равно любому из полученых ID из первой базы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно, самый простой вариант:

```
SELECT * FROM `MySQL_TABLE` WHERE `ID2` IN (тут перечисление ID из первого запроса через запятую);
```